# heroku: scaling dynos from node app

Tags: heroku

Using the [heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line) it is possible to scale dynos like so:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

But I'd like to be able to scale dynos from *within my node app* (running on heroku, so I can't just `exec` the above command because the CLI isn't available), e.g. to respond dynamically to changes in load.

I am vaguely familiar with the [heroku client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-client) package, but can't see how it could be used for dyno scaling.

Answer (score 3):

So curiousity got the better of me, and I seem to have worked out an answer to my own question...

The key is to use the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference), which is accessed in the node app using the [heroku-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-client) package mentioned in my question.

The Heroku API has a [Formation Update](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation-update) interface, which allows you to set the scale (or quantity) of the web dynos.

The following example scales the web dyno to 2:

```
var Heroku = require('heroku-client');
var heroku = new Heroku({ token: process.env.HEROKU_API_TOKEN });

heroku.patch('/apps/yourappname/formation/web', { body: {"quantity": 2} }).then(response => {
    console.log('patch response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

... where `yourappname` is of course your app's name.